# Disappearing data when saving an R list

Tags: r, list, save

After two years of R programming, I thought that I may have mastered saving an object onto disk and then retrieving the data.

I have trying to save a list() onto disk and then retrieve it.  Here is the code to save the list.

```
object.size(lst_html_results) # results in 5816 bytes
save(lst_html_results, file = "example_file.RData")
```

When I have the file "example_file.RData" in my computer's file system (MAC OS). It reports the file as being 203 bytes...????

And then I retrieve the file into memory using the following command:

```
rm(list = ls())
load(file = "example_file.RData")
```

And I can observer the structure of the list for example:

```
names(lst_html_results)
```

Produces expected results.

But when I try to observe some data in the lists's nodes

```
lst_html_results[[1]]
```

The system crashes.

Despite my file system reporting that the file is only 203 bytes.  When I load the file into R, using the following:

```
load(file = "example_file.RData")
```

It then reports an object size of 5816 bytes.

Basically, it seems as through R is saving and loading the list as expected. Except that the saved list does not contain any data....????

Help...!!!

Comment: I guess that parts of `lst_html_results` are made of `externalptr` type of objects, which are just references to `C` structures, are not handled directly by `R` and cannot be saved through `save`, since just the pointer value will be saved, but not the content of the pointed memory. Can you give us more info about your object before it gets corrupted?

Comment: have you tried saveRDS and readRDS? they usually keep R objects completely intact.

Comment: Hi @nicola.  I think that you are correct.  Each element was a class of "xml_document".  I have since converted these to text [i.e as.character() ] and the results are as I expected.  Do you know whether there is a more general solution to this problem...?  How can I convert the externalptr references into something that R can save...?

Comment: There is no a general way to save external pointers in R. Usually, packages that make use of external pointers provide functions to coerce them to an ordinary R object (i.e. the `as.character` method you mentioned) or to save the object into a format specific for that object (in the `XML` case, the function `saveXML`).

Comment: can you share the output of `dput(lst_html_results)`?

Comment: Yep here we go @inscaven:   structure(list(node = <pointer: 0x122790050>, doc = <pointer: 0x129588220>), .Names = c("node", 
"doc"), class = c("xml_document", "xml_node"))

Comment: To put my original question into context.  I am trying to save a collection (about 300 ) html pages a single object.  My original thought was collect these html pages into a list and then save the list.